# error: 'sumProduct' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

So the question is: Write a program to generate the product of the numbers in the range [1, 10).

So, I assume that to be the total value of 1*2, 2*3,3*4 etc.. n*n+1 till n = 9.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  int product = 1;

    for (product = 1; product< 10; ++product) {

        int sumProduct = product * (product + 1);

    }
  std::cout << sumProduct << std::endl;
}
```

My errors:

```
In function 'int main()':
11:9: warning: unused variable 'sumProduct' [-Wunused-variable]
14:16: error: 'sumProduct' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: If by "total value" you mean the sum of those numbers, you're wrong. The product of the numbers in [1, 10) is `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error given by the compiler: `14:16: error: 'sumProduct' was not declared in this scope`.
Whenever you declare variables in a statement block i.e. `{ ... }`, the variables are only accessible within that block. More specifically, the variable will get destroyed once they go out of scope. The simple solution is to declare them outside like so

```
int main()
{ // begin block 1
  int product = 1;
  int sumProduct = 0; // declare the variable here...
    for (product = 1; product< 10; ++product) { // begin block 2

        sumProduct = product * (product + 1);

    } // end block 2
  std::cout << sumProduct << std::endl;
} // end block 1 sumProduct will 'die' here
```

There is still a problem with the logic of your code, if what I think of what you want to have happen is correct.

Comment: That fixes the compiler error, but now every loop iteration overwrites `sumProduct`. The final value is just `9 * 10`.

Comment: That's why I added the extra bit of comment at the end, I am just solving the compilation problem...I am not doing his homework

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this issue simply because of scoping.

`sumProduct` is defined inside this loop.

```
for (product = 1; product< 10; ++product) {
    int sumProduct = product * (product + 1);
} // sumProduct dies here.
```

So, When you try to access it outside the loop, it won't be visible in that scope.

```
std::cout << sumProduct << std::endl; // not visible here.
```

What I suggest you is to define `sumProduct` in the block outside the scope of the loop.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int product = 1;
    int sumProduct = 1;

    for (product = 1; product< 10; ++product) {
        sumProduct *= product;
    }

    std::cout << sumProduct << std::endl; // sumProduct is in the same scope. So, it is visible.
}
```

Comment: @JKong Can you please tell me how can I improve my answer?

Comment: Yours is good it's just that the other answer also mentions the error with the logic, if you look at my example logic within the for loop (just purely the logic, regardless if the whole code compiles). You can see that the sumProduct variable does not store the cumulated value of the product. It was a very insightful answer though! Cheers

Comment: @JKong I didn't get your point regarding **accumulated value**. The current code stores this value: 1 * 2 + 2 * 3 + 3 * 4 + ... Can you please elaborate on your requirement?

Comment: If by "total value" you mean the sum of those numbers, you're wrong. The product of the numbers in [1, 10) is 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 that was one of the comments and the other was There is still a problem with the logic of your code, if what I think of what you want to have happen is correct. So it requires the product of the numbers which is the product of 1-9 since it is a half open range, I understand this problem now and I've got the code running

Comment: @JKong I have edited my answer to meet your requirement. Now, it does the same as you told.

Comment: @JKong One more thing. You posted in the question that you required **total value of  1*2, 2*3,3*4**... From this part, one will interpret it in the same way that I implemented earlier. I think You should have mentioned product directly instead.

Comment: you want me to accept your answer with the green tick?

Comment: I copy and pasted the book question, I misinterpreted the meaning and was incorrect, the others spotted that

Comment: @JKong No requirement as such. I just wanted to know the reason. That's it. Earlier, I think you accepted my answer. Then you took it back. Its ok. OP has to decide which answer is better.

Comment: Alright all cleared up then, thanks a lot for the help though. Nice work on the reputation score and keep up the good work. I gave you answer an upvote.